# Why Laravel does not insert row?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Inserting operation is:

```
$r = [
'idVisitor' => 4,
'lastname' => 'fg',
'firstname' => '11',
'document_number' => '444',
'idEvent' => 2
];

$g = Visitor::insert($r);
```

**Model is:**

```
class Visitor extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'visitors';

    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'middlename', 'document_number', 'pincode', 'ckecked', 'date_cheked', 'user_cheked', 'company', 'code', 'status', 'idEvent', 'date', 'birthday'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'idVisitor';

}
```

if to do this:

```
$g = Visitor::insert($r);
var_dump($g);
```

It gives me true, so Laravel considers that it was committed.

**Dump SQL is:**

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `idVisitor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pincode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ckecked` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_cheked` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_cheked` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idEvent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `visitors`
--
ALTER TABLE `visitors`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idVisitor`,`idEvent`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `document_number_UNIQUE` (`document_number`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `pincode_UNIQUE` (`pincode`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
  ADD KEY `fk_visitors_users1_idx` (`user_cheked`),
  ADD KEY `fk_visitors_events1_idx` (`idEvent`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `visitors`
--
ALTER TABLE `visitors`
  MODIFY `idVisitor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=18;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `visitors`
--
ALTER TABLE `visitors`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_visitors_events1` FOREIGN KEY (`idEvent`) REFERENCES `events` (`idEvent`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_visitors_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_cheked`) REFERENCES `users` (`idUser`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
COMMIT;
```

I use MySQL 5.0.12

Also I tried:

```
 $g = new Visitor();
    $g->lastname = 4;
    $g->middlename = 4;
    $g->document_number = 444;
    $g->firstname = 4;
    $g->idEvent = 2;
    $g->save();
```

Comment: make `idVisitor` fillable?

Comment: It is autoincrement and primary key

Comment: I tried to add `idVisitor` in fillable. No result

Comment: `Visitor::create($r)` then? i never use `::insert` not sure if its different

Comment: I tried insert and create, no matter, it says that inserted okay, but there is no row in table: `$g = Visitor::insert($r);` or `$g = Visitor::create($r);`

Comment: i cant see the problem, are you looking at the right database? check your `.env` and make sure it is not cached in `app/bootstrap/cache` by clearing that dir

Comment: Yes, I work with right db.I can delete from this table

Comment: MySQL 5.0.12 That's dated September 02, 2005!  That's 13½ years old!

Comment: It is in package Xampp by default

Comment: Even XAmpp is currently at 5.6.40-1 (MySQL) and 7.1.26 (MariaDB)

Comment: I will try update Mysql, perhaps it is cause

Comment: I don't think it's the cause; it's just nuts to run THAT old software if there's perfectly newer version(s) available (especially if that machine is connected to the web).

Comment: You have 2 primary keys in your table: `ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idVisitor`,`idEvent`)` could that be the problem? `idEvent` should be a (positive) integer, no a prim key. It is not laravel that refuses to enter a new row, it is MySQL that refuses.

Comment: Yes, I have two keys, but both of tables are empty, so there is no conflict within keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use

```
$g = new Visitor();

$g->idVisitor = 4;
$g->firstname= 4;
$g->idVisitor = 4
$g->save();
```

this is another way

Comment: $g = new Visitor();

$g->idVisitor = 4;
$g->firstname= 4;
$g->idVisitor = 4
$g->save();

Comment: please check and inform me

Comment: It also does not work: `         $g = new Visitor();
            $g->lastname = 4;
            $g->middlename = 4;
            $g->document_number = 444;
            $g->firstname = 4;
            $g->idEvent = 2;
            $g->save();
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189983/discussion-between-opv-and-anandu-krishna).

Comment: Sir, sorry for interrupting, my internet connection is lost, but I can not fix it still

Answer (score 1):

$g = new Visitor(); call class without '()', so  $g = new Visitor;